# How to directly access a button from a table td

Tags: css, reactjs, button, sass

I am currently designing a table that was made with **rc-table**. I made the last row for actions which renders the buttons `edit` and `delete`. I want to edit it's style with **Sass** but I was unable to

I also specified classes for both the edit and delete button since they'll have different background-colors.

Is it possible to access it directly via a class? or is there another way which I don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have something like this in your code

```
this.columns = [
  {
    title: 'Operations', dataIndex: '', key: 'd', render: (text, record) =>
    <a className="delete-btn" onClick={e => this.onDelete(record.key, e)} href="#">Delete</a>,
  },
];
```

you can add class t the `a` element and the overwrite those styles with your CSS/SASS.

like this

```
.rc-table td {
  background-color: 'red';
  // custom styles here
}
```

notice the `className` attribute in `a`.